# jQuery focusout event data isn't passed, why?

Tags: jquery

The next code doesn't work properly:

```
 jQuery(this).focusout({ currObj : currEditableObj},cancelRename(event));

function cancelRename(event){
    var currObj = event.data.currObj;
    currObj.removeClass("focusedEditableDiv");
    currObj.parent().find('.renamePanel').hide();
}
```

I want to be able to use the currObj but the event doesn't have event.data at all.
What am I doing wrong ?

Edit: I've noticed that when going with the debugger on the "event" it says it's a MouseEvent

Comment: try currObj.focusout(cancelRename);
Ref : http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: @KD Thanks, worked as a charm, how come my way didn't work ?

Comment: checkout the documentation here
http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: @KD, yep I've read it before I've posted here, I guess I didn't understand it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and check if it works properly

```
currObj.focusout(cancelRename);
```

for more information on jQuery.focuout **[clich here](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)**